# How to create a batch file in Mac?

Tags: macos, bash, batch-file, terminal, applescript

I need to find a solution at work to backup specific folders daily, hopefully to a RAR or ZIP file.

If it was on PC, I would have done it already. But I don't have any idea to how to approach it on a Mac.

What I basically want to achieve is **an automated task, that can be run with an executable, that does:**

1. compress a specific directory (`/Volumes/Audio/Shoko`) to a rar or zip file.

   **(in the zip file exclude all *.wav files in all sub Directories and a directory names "Videos").**
2. move It to a network share (`/Volumes/Post Shared/Backup From Sound`).

   **(or compress directly to this folder).**
3. automate the file name of the Zip file with dynamic date and time (so no duplicate file names).
4. Shutdown Mac when finished.

I want to say again, I don't usually use Mac, so things like what kind of file to open for the script, and stuff like that is not trivial for me, yet.

I have tried to put Mark's bash lines (from the first answer, below) in a txt file and executed it, but it had errors and didn't work.

I also tried to use Automator, but it's too plain, no advanced options.

How can I accomplish this?

I would love a working example :)

Thank You,

Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just make a `bash` script that does the backup and then you can either double-click it or run it on a schedule. I don't know your paths and/or tools of choice, but some thing along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=`date +"/Volumes/path/to/network/share/Backup/%Y-%m-%d.tgz"`
cd /directory/to/backup || exit 1
tar -cvz "$FILENAME" .
```

You can save that on your Desktop as `backup` and then go in Terminal and type:

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/backup
```

to make it executable. Then you can just double click on it - obviously after changing the paths to reflect what you want to backup and where to.

Also, you may prefer to use some other tools - such as `rsync` but the method is the same.

Comment: Hi mark, I hadn't had the chance to try it yet, rest assure that once I will , I will update/mark as an answer

Comment: im not sure I know how to do it . am I suppose to just create a new text file with the text editor, or what ? its not going to well :)

Comment: You can't save it as RTF, it needs to be plain text.

Comment: +1 This should work once you figure out how to save as a proper text file.

Comment: yeah I did , and the bash did run, but no output file , just tons of gibberish on the terminal window :(

Comment: Ok, try simplifying the script to just the first line, then `echo hello` on  the second line, then `read z` on the third line. Put a hash (`#`) at the start of all your other lines to comment them out.