# Make an executable file on a mac

Tags: python, macos, batch-file

I have tried to gather as much information as possible before posting this question but have had little luck. (I posted the links below.)

I have a file called "Intro.py" at this path, "programming/py_projects/Incubator/Course".

I have a file called "Python.command" on my desktop. Within the command file I have the following lines:

```
cd ../programming/py_projects/Incubator/Course
bash python Intro.py
```

When I run the command file (double click), terminal opens and this is the result:

```
/Users/muhs_a/Desktop/Python.command: line 1: cd: ../programming
/py_projects/Incubator/course: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/python: /use/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
logout
```

I just want to be able to double click on the Python.command file and have the program written in Intro.py to run in the terminal. Where am I going wrong?

[How to create a batch file in mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235324/how-to-create-a-batch-file-in-mac)
[Why do people write #!/usr/bin/env python on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)
[How do I make this file.sh executable via double click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409946/how-do-i-make-this-file-sh-executable-via-double-click)

Comment: Make sure that the file opens with terminal. Right click, get info, open with. To give a file execute permissions. Open terminal type in chmod +x pathtofile.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that the directory `../programming/py_projects/Incubator/course` doesn't exist from the context of the location from which you call this `.command` file.

Comment: Also why don't you just write a shell file. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338066/mac-osx-execute-a-python-script-at-startup

Comment: @msanti It does open with terminal and tries to run. I just get what is shown above. I'll take a look at the link. Thanks.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 What do you mean, "...from the context of the location from which you call this .command file"?

Comment: I just meant your present working directory when you call this file - important for relative paths. Also check the case: the given content of the `.command` file says `Course`, but the error says `course`.

Comment: I changed the top line to : cd ~/Programming/py_projects/Incubator/Course The error now only has the line that says /usr/bin/python: /use/bin/python: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 1):

Open up the Terminal and run `chmod +x ~/programming/py_projects/Incubator/Course` (I'm assuming that the directory programming is in your home dir). This command changes the permissions on your script to make it executable.

Comment: Just ran it. Still no luck.

Comment: I changed the top line to :    cd ~/Programming/py_projects/Incubator/Course    The error now only has the line that says    /usr/bin/python: /use/bin/python: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed my Python.command file to:

```
#!/bin/bash
python ~/Programming/py_projects/Incubator/Course
```

I then got an error that said:

```
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in...
```

I then changed the name of the file from Intro.py to reflect the missing module and it runs perfectly.

Comment: If you just want to run the script in Terminal you can just run ```python ~/Programming/py_projects/Incubator/Course``` directly from the command line. No need for an extra command file.

Comment: Right. I wanted to use the command file. I am trying to learn how these things work. Thank you though.